# L-lysine acetate synthesis

Tags: amino-acids, synthesis

Is it possible to synthesize L-lysine acetate in the following steps? First, mix L-lysine HCl with an excess of NaOH and just enough water so that the total water in the product is enough to solve all NaCl. Decant the water to obtain L-lysine free base. Then either mix with excess (concentrated) acetic acid and dry the product in a hermetic environment with silica gel, or pour acetic acid in a pot, wrap a cheesecloth on the top, spread l-lysine over it and let the acetic acid steam gently without cooking the lysine.

**Aside:** According to an [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1818087614000671) from 2015, L-lysine is usually available in hydrochloride and acetate forms because the free base form is unstable. However, L-lysine acetate seems to have gone out of the market. Is there a reason for that? Is l-lysine citrate also stable and could it be made by simply mixing l-lysine free base with citric acid?

Comment: In principle yes. That is essentially what is done in this patent: https://patents.google.com/patent/CN102070477B/en